# Official pop emails are mixed with my gmail emails

Tags: gmail

I wanted to check all my emails from one tool, gmail was the obvious choice for me. So I configured my official pop email on gmail instead of thunderbird or other linux based email tools.

But the mails are all mixed up with my gmail, making it impossible to differentiate between personal and official emails.

Comment: Don't they have categories in Gmail? There's Personal, Work etc and you can create categories in your gmail account can't you?

Comment: I'll look into it and report back.

Comment: Cant create a category. Its offered under Google Business priced model I think. There is no "free" way of doing it.

Comment: Nope, does not work. Categories cannot be used to filter emails from @officialdomain.com.

Comment: Don't gmail automatically "label" the one coming via your POP account? Or you want to completely separate them? (example: Stuff to my gmail are just labelled Inbox. Stuff from my POP acc are labelled: inbox, myemail@mydomain.com)

Comment: They have a way of categorizing email, called labels, which are like tags. you can then choose to display all or to display just mail matching a particular tag

Comment: Why do you not want to do it with Thunderbird?  Thunderbird does what you are looking for by default.  If you want access from any location, just look at other web mail that offers email gathering.